# Is there a known way to validate an Estonian business ID?

Tags: php, validation, checksum

I have to validate an Estonian business ID (not a citizen ID). The ID is 9 numbers, but I think there might be a system of assigning them. For example, here is the Finnish validation with the last number as the checksum

```
if (preg_match('/^\d{7}-\d{1}$/', $user_input)) {
    list($num, $control) = preg_split('[-]', $user_input);
    // Add leading zeros if number is < 7
    $num         = str_pad($num, 7, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $controlSum  = 0;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 0, 1)*7;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 1, 1)*9;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 2, 1)*10;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 3, 1)*5;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 4, 1)*8;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 5, 1)*4;
    $controlSum += (int)substr($num, 6, 1)*2;
    $controlSum  = $controlSum%11;
    if ($controlSum == 0) {
        return ($controlSum == $control) ? true : false;
    } elseif ($controlSum >= 2 && $controlSum <= 10 ) {
        return ((11 - $controlSum) == $control) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Usually there is a checksum for all of these types of IDs, so it's not just a matter of running a regex on it, but I can't find anything relating to Estonian businesses.

Any links to known libraries, examples would be appreciated. I'm working in PHP, but these could be in any language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a SOAP-Call from the European Commission https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vatRequest.html

It should work like this (not 100% tested):

```
$vatId = "{{the vat id }}";

$client = new SoapClient("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");
if ($client) {
     $cc           = substr($vatId, 0, 2);
     $vn           = substr($vatId, 2);
     $params       = array('countryCode' => $cc, 'vatNumber' => $vn);
     $result = $client->checkVat($params);
     if ($result->valid == true) {
        echo "VAT-ID ok";
     }
} else {
    die("connection failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea, but I don't think I'm allowed to use a 3rd party service in the app. It's a pity they can't release the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library, which answers my question

https://github.com/arthurdejong/python-stdnum/blob/master/stdnum/ee/registrikood.py

```
from stdnum.exceptions import *
from stdnum.util import clean, isdigits

def calc_check_digit(number):
    """Calculate the check digit."""
    check = sum(((i % 9) + 1) * int(n)
                for i, n in enumerate(number[:-1])) % 11
    if check == 10:
        check = sum((((i + 2) % 9) + 1) * int(n)
                    for i, n in enumerate(number[:-1])) % 11
    return str(check % 10)

def compact(number):
    """Convert the number to the minimal representation. This strips the
    number of any valid separators and removes surrounding whitespace."""
    return clean(number, ' ').strip()


def validate(number):
    """Check if the number provided is valid. This checks the length and
    check digit."""
    number = compact(number)
    if not isdigits(number):
        raise InvalidFormat()
    if len(number) != 8:
        raise InvalidLength()
    if number[0] not in '1789':
        raise InvalidComponent()
    if number[-1] != calc_check_digit(number):
        raise InvalidChecksum()
    return number


def is_valid(number):
    """Check if the number provided is valid. This checks the length and
    check digit."""
    try:
        return bool(validate(number))
    except ValidationError:
        return False
```